# C zlib link errors

Tags: c, zlib

I am trying to learn the zlib module, however when i compile my code it always says that all the function names provided by zlib are not defined. Here is my code, any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zlib.h>

int compressFile(char *infilename, char *outfilename){
        //Opens the needed files
        FILE * infile = fopen(infilename, "rb");
        gzFile outfile = gzopen(outfilename, "wb");
        //Checks if the files are correctly opened
        if (!infile || !outfile) return -1;

        char inbuffer[128];
        int numRead = 0;

        while ((numRead = fread(inbuffer, 1, sizeof(inbuffer), infile)) > 0){
                gzwrite(outfile, inbuffer, numRead);

        }
        fclose(infile);
        gzclose(outfile);

}
```

Here is the error

```
cc     test.c   -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:24:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘comressFile’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  comressFile("hello.txt", "hello.zip");
  ^
/tmp/cc32e8i4.o: In function `compressFile':
test.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `gzopen'
test.c:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `gzwrite'
test.c:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `gzclose'
/tmp/cc32e8i4.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `comressFile'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link with zlib:

```
cc -lz test.c -o test
```

Also your spelling is wrong. "compressFile" vs. "comressFile".

Remember, in C **declaring functions before using them is optional**. If you don't do it, or spell the name wrong, the function is implicitly declared at first use, which is probably not what you want.